# Jsonpath doesn't work when used out of Angular Library Bundle

Tags: angular, jsonpath, angular-library

I have a project where I'm creating an Angular Library, that is imported in another app as a UMD bundle.

I wanted to use [Jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) library to parse json in one of the components in the library. When I try to use json path directly in the angular app, it works fine. But if I try to do the same thing in the library component, I get error saying

> "ERROR TypeError: this.nodes is not a function"

Here's how I am trying to use it:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as JP from 'jsonpath/jsonpath';

@Component({
  selector: 'nom-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const t = {id:1};
    const r = JP.query(t, '$..*');
    console.log(r)
  }

}
```

This works if the test-component is directly in the app, but doesn't if the component is in the library.
I've tried using ng-packagr options "umdModuleId", externals but none of them seem to work.

If I try to add jsonpath to bundleDependencies in my library's package.json,
I get the error

> 'query' is not exported by 'node_modules\jsonpath\jsonpath.js'
>   Blockquote

I'm completely stumped on what could be causing this.